# Dagger 2 module dependency graph: bound multiple times

Tags: dagger, dagger-2

I'm new to Dagger 2, trying to port a (quite) complex application to it.

We have several dependencies on 'common' libraries (shared with other projects). Those 'common' libraries sometimes depend on other 'common' libraries. Each library exposes a module.

An example:

```java
@Module
public class JsonModule {
    @Provides
    public Mapper provideMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new DefaultMapper(objectMapper);
    }

    @Provides
    public ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
        return ObjectMapperFactory.build();
    }
}
```

Our HttpModule depends on the JsonModule:

```java
@Module(includes = {JsonModule.class})
public class HttpModule {
    public HttpHelper provideHttpHelper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new DefaultHttpHelper(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

Finally in my application, I depend on both these modules:

```java
@Module(includes = {JsonModule.class, HttpModule.class})
public class MyAppModule {
    public Service1 provideService1(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new DefaultService1(objectMapper);
    }

    public Service2 provideService2(Mapper mappper) {
        return new DefaultService2(mappper);
    }
}
```

I then have 1 component that depends on my MyAppModule:

```java
@Component(modules = MyAppModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface MyAppComponent {
    public Service2 service2();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I compile the project, I get a Dagger compiler error:

```java
[ERROR] com.company.json.Mapper is bound multiple times:
[ERROR] @Provides com.company.json.Mapper com.company.json.JsonModule.provideMapper(com.company.json.ObjectMapper)
[ERROR] @Provides com.company.json.Mapper com.company.json.JsonModule.provideMapper(com.company.json.ObjectMapper)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it wrong to depend on a module twice in the same dependency graph?

Comment: maybe because you include it once in HttpModule and again in MyAppModule, try removing the `includes JsonModule` in one of those places

Answer (score 10):

In your `MyAppModule` you shouldn't include `JsonModule`, it is included by dagger implicitly. When including `HttpModule` dagger will automatically include all modules which `HttpModule` includes (in your case that is `JsonModule`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem is related to our project's situation:

- the common projects combine Groovy and Java
- the common projects are built using Gradle
- the application project combines Groovy and Java
- the application project was built using Maven and the groovy-eclipse-compiler

Basicly: I blame the groovy-eclipse-compiler for now. I converted the project to Gradle, and everything works now.