# Dagger 2 dependency graph is bound multiple times

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have looked into multiple posts on this issue, but none of the suggested solutions seem to solve my problem. Some of the posts I have looked are given below

1. [error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] com.example.StartRouter is bound multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761359/error-dagger-duplicatebindings-com-example-startrouter-is-bound-multiple-time)
2. [Dagger 2 module dependency graph: bound multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721081/dagger-2-module-dependency-graph-bound-multiple-times)
3. [Dagger2 Error at inject in a class who injects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688817/dagger2-error-at-inject-in-a-class-who-injects)

But I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is my set up. I am injecting a class named `NotificationManager` in two separate classes. The cases are given below

## 1

```
class PushJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
    @Inject
    PushService pushService

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent)
    {
        .. Do Work . . . 
    }
}
```

PushService is a simple POJO whose instance dependency graph is as follows. NotificationManager is injected into PushService through the constructor.

```
PushService -> NotificationManager -> (Context, Map <String, NotificationBuilder>)
```

In this example, PushService depends on NotificationManager which depends on Android Context, and Map in which case NotificationBuilder is a POJO that accepts Context as a constructor argument.

We have a common AppModule in which all dependencies are defined, and this is how is it set up

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {PushServiceModule.class})
abstract PushJobIntentService contributePushJobIntentServiceInjector();
```

`PushServiceModule` injects the dependencies as follows:

```
@Module(includes = {NotificationManagerModule.class})
public abstract class PushServiceModule
{
    . . . Dependenies of PushService . . . 
}
```

NotificationManagerModule

```
@Module()
public abstract class NotificationManagerModule
{
    @Provides
    static Map<String, NotificationBuilder> provideNotificationBuilders(Context context)
    {
        Map<String, NotificationBuilder> builders = new HashMap<>();
        builders.put("Key1",new NotificationBuilder(context, "Key1", "Text1"));
        return Collections.unModifiableMap(builders);
    }
}
```

## 2

The second dependency graph is as follows

```
AppSignOutHelper -> LoggedOutTask (Async Task) -> NotificationManager
```

I am attempting to inject NotificationManager into LoggedOutTask. AppSignOutHelper implements SignOutHelper and is defined as follows

```
/**
 * Binds the {@link AppSignOutHelper} instance to the shared {@link SignOutHelper} interface.
 */
@Binds
@Qualifier
abstract SignOutHelper bindSignOutHelper(AppSignOutHelper appSignOutHelper);
```

**ISSUE**

When I try to compile the project, this is the error that I get

```
/Users/username/sourcecode/android/app/src/main/java/com/myproject/mobile/dagger/AppComponent.java:50: warning: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager is bound multiple times:
public interface AppComponent extends DomainComponent
       ^
      @Inject com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager(android.content.Context, Map<String,com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationBuilder>) [com.myproject.android.dagger.AppComponent]
      @Provides com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManagerModule.provideNotificationManager(android.content.Context, Map<String,com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationBuilder>) [com.myproject.android.dagger.AppComponent → com.myproject.android.dagger.AppModule_ContributePushJobIntentServiceInjector.PushJobIntentServiceSubcomponent]
  This condition was never validated before, and will soon be an error. See https://dagger.dev/conflicting-inject.
      com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager is injected at
          com.myproject.android.notifications.PushService( myproject.NotificationManager)
      com.myproject.android.notifications.PushService is injected at
          com.myproject.android.notifications.PushJobIntentService.pushService
      com.myproject.android.notifications.PushJobIntentService is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myproject.android.dagger.AppComponent → com.myproject.android.dagger.AppModule_ContributePushJobIntentServiceInjector.PushJobIntentServiceSubcomponent]
/Users/username/sourcecode/android/app/src/main/java/com/myproject/mobile/dagger/AppComponent.java:50: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationBuilder> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface AppComponent extends DomainComponent
       ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.myproject.android.dagger.AppModule_ContributePushJobIntentServiceInjector.PushJobIntentServiceSubcomponent
      java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationBuilder> is injected at
          com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager(…, notifBuilderMap)
      com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager is injected at
          com.myproject.android.notifications.CreateLoggedOutNotificationTask(…, myproject.NotificationManager)
      javax.inject.Provider<com.myproject.android.notifications.CreateLoggedOutNotificationTask> is injected at
          com.myproject.android.AppSignOutHelper(…, loggedOutNotificationTask, …)
      com.myproject.android.AppSignOutHelper is injected at
          com.myproject.android.dagger.AppModule.bindSignOutHelper(appSignOutHelper)
     com.myproject.android.SignOutHelper is injected at
          com.myproject.android.dagger.DomainModule.provideSignOutHelper(…, optionalInstance)
      com.myproject.android.SignOutHelper is provided at
          com.myproject.android.dagger.DomainComponent.getSignOutHelper()
1 error
1 warning
```

But if I don't include the `NotificationManagerModule` in PushServiceModule and leave it as follows:

```
@Module()
public abstract class PushServiceModule
{
    . . . Dependenies of PushService . . . 
}
```

I get the following error

```
/Users/username/sourcecode/android/app/src/main/java/com/myproject/mobile/dagger/AppComponent.java:50: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationBuilder> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
    public interface AppComponent extends DomainComponent
           ^
          java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationBuilder> is injected at
              com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager(…, notifBuilderMap)
          com.myproject.android.notifications.NotificationManager is injected at
              com.myproject.android.notifications.CreateLoggedOutNotificationTask(NotificationManager)
          javax.inject.Provider<com.myproject.android.notifications.CreateLoggedOutNotificationTask> is injected at
              com.myproject.android.AppSignOutHelper(…, loggedOutNotificationTask, …)
          com.myproject.android.AppSignOutHelper is injected at
              com.myproject.android.dagger.AppModule.bindSignOutHelper(appSignOutHelper)
           com.myproject.android.SignOutHelper is injected at
              com.myproject.android.dagger.DomainModule.provideSignOutHelper(…, optionalInstance)
          com.myproject.android.SignOutHelper is provided at
              com.myproject.android.dagger.DomainComponent.getSignOutHelper()
      The following other entry points also depend on it:
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myproject.android.dagger.AppComponent → com.myproject.android.dagger.AppModule_ContributePushJobIntentServiceInjector.PushJobIntentServiceSubcomponent]
    1 error
```

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

I want to be able to inject `NotificationManager` in to `CreateLoggedOutTask` which in turn will be injected into `AppSignOutHelper`. What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your main error is ```cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method```, am I right?

Comment: and where did you provide context? I don't have experience with daggerAndroid. will this provide the context?

Comment: @MasoudDarzi I don't know the answer. I have tried both.

Comment: @MasoudDarzi I am providing the context instance